# Can't get the iPad to vibrate

Tags: objective-c, ipad

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

This line of code does not seem to work on the iPad - does the iPad have the hardware required to vibrate?

Comment: The only way to make an iPad vibrate is to shake it

Comment: There must be an easier way to get your thrills.

Comment: hehe yes I will have to find another way lol.  I am working through a textbook but I am using the iPad SDK instead of the iPhone SDK so have been encountering a few parts of the book where I just can't complete the exercises like camera and vibrate :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't have a physical vibrate mechanism, it doesn't appear in the specs: http://www.apple.com/ipad/compare/

Also take a look at http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=890432

Comment: To be fair, [the iPhone specs](http://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/) don't mention vibration, either.

Answer (score 0):

iPads doesn't support physical vibration. You can use these codes only in case of iPhones and newer versions of iPod.