# Does iPad 2 Vibrate?

Tags: ipad, ipad-2

Simple question, but only rumours on the Internet - I'm working on an app and don't yet have one!

I read this: [Can't get the iPad to vibrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227526/cant-get-the-ipad-to-vibrate) but this is only the first one - also the tech-specs don't mention it, but the iPhone tech-specs don't either!

Less than 24 hours before they get to the UK :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it does not vibrate. That line of code is in the SDK because the same SDK is used for other devices. In the same way, you can code in use of the camera on an iPad 1 or an iPod 3, but it won't do anything.

Comment: Thanks - thats that documented!

Answer (score 3):

My iPad 2 has never vibrated, and there are no settings that indicate it can.